# Thread.join() not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This is the comple java class (GFXSurface). Inside this class, a second class is defined,

```
public class GFXSurface extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    AnotherSurface ourSurfaceView;
    float x, y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ourSurfaceView = new AnotherSurface(this);
        ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSurfaceView.ourPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        ourSurfaceView.ourResume();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        return true;  
    }

    /*------------------------Class within a class-------------------------------*/

    public class AnotherSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
        Thread ourThread = null;
        boolean isRunning;

        public AnotherSurface(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context); //not auto-generated; set it up manually
            isRunning = false;
            ourHolder = getHolder();    
        }

        public void ourPause(){
            isRunning = false;
            while(true){
                try {
                    ourThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            ourThread = null;
        }

        public void ourResume(){
            isRunning = true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(true){
                if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(255, 0, 0);
                if(x!=0 && y!=0){
                    Bitmap ourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_ball);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(ourBitmap, x-(ourBitmap.getWidth()/2), y-(ourBitmap.getHeight()/2), null);
                }
                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I start the activity, it works as is required, it creates a bitmap at the place where the screen is clicked (centered at the point of click). The problem it gives is that, when I press the back key on my phone, the app stops responding and the phone gives an option to force shut the app. I think the it has got to do something with the "ourThread" thread not being joined properly.

Any idea where the problem lies?  Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** I have actually found where I was going wrong. In the while loop:

```
while(true){
        if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawRGB(255, 0, 0);
        if(x!=0 && y!=0){
            Bitmap ourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_ball);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ourBitmap, x-(ourBitmap.getWidth()/2), y-(ourBitmap.getHeight()/2), null);
        }
```

I just changed "true" to "isRunning". And now the thread does end, and thus, the activity closes on pressing the back button. Thanks all for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What is your thread doing, maybe it's in some loop?

Comment: You never break out of your loop...so the thread will never end. The call to `join()` will never return.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So how should I add a return()?

Comment: Just get rid of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that, "ourThread" never stops when it is joined.

You have to realize that calling `ourThread.join()` only *waits* for the thread to finish -- it won't stop the thread.  Your `ourThread` may be hung for some reason.  A thread dump will show where it is running.  Maybe it is stuck in a loop?  Maybe it is waiting on a network connection?

If the `join()` returns successfully, by definition, the thread was was joined is no longer running.  So the thread calling `ourThread.join()` will wait until the `ourThread` thread has completed.

If the thread is no longer running then maybe there are other threads running keeping your application open?  A [thread dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589074/how-to-make-java-thread-dump-in-android) will show you what [other non-daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505720/179850) are still around.  They will need to terminate before your application will stop.

In looking at your thread code, I don't see any way for you to exit the infinite loop unless a `RuntimeException` is thrown.  When does the thread stop working?  Did you mean to do a `break;` instead of a `continue;`?

```
while(true){
    if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
        continue; // should this be a break?
    Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawRGB(255, 0, 0);
    ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Now that you've added more code, you need to make `isRunning` be `volatile` so that multiple threads can update it and see the updates and you should change the `while` loop in your `run()` method to be:

```
private volatile boolean isRunning;
...
while(!isRunning){
```

Comment: join is not returning -- this is why he/she is seeing the ANR

Comment: "join is not returning"? I don't get it. What does it mean?

Comment: @BornAgain it means you call join and that is where your program stays. The other thread never joins because it is in an endless loop.

Comment: `join()` only _waits_ for `ourThread` to finish.  It doesn't stop the thread @BornAgain.  The `ourThread` is still running so the caller is waiting in the `join()` method.

Comment: @Gray  I have updated my question. Can you please narrow down the problem now? Thanks!

Comment: @BornAgain We have narrowed down the problem to the infinite loop. Get rid of it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just did what you said. But it still is giving the same error.

Comment: To put it more explicitly, change "while (true)" in the run method to "while (isRunning)"

Comment: +1 user1676075 although it needs to be `while(!isRunning)` and you need to make `isRunning` be `volatile @BornAgain.

Comment: @Gray Instead of "!isRunning", "isRunning" closes the activity. It does take me back to the previous activity. But then I get the error "Unfortunately, the app has stopped".
PS: Sorry for the late reply, I was away for some time.

Comment: @Gray I have made an edit to my question. Can you please help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Dude you can't change the question like that because it completely invalidates my answer and my work @BornAgain.  Ask another question instead.

Comment: @Gray Okay. Sorry about that. Actually I have solved my problem. I have edited my question for that. Thanks for your help!