# Why does this simple Akka Streams program never terminate?

Tags: akka-stream

Should be a simple question.  I'm using Akka 2.4.2 (contains Akka Streams & HTTP).  I expected this `Source` to complete & the program to terminate because the `Source` is finite, but it never does.  Why doesn't this program terminate?

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.collection.immutable._
import akka._
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.util._

object Test extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val s = Source.single(1)
  s.runForeach(println)
}
```

Output:

```
$ sbt run
...
[info] Running Test
[DEBUG] [02/23/2016 10:59:19.904] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://TestSystem)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [02/23/2016 10:59:19.904] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://TestSystem)] Default Loggers started
1
```

Relevant portion of my `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion  := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaVersion = "2.4.2"
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %%  "akka-stream" % akkaVersion
  )
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because Akka uses [non-daemonic threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505682/java-daemon-thread-and-non-daemon-thread), so it'll keep the app running until you shut-down the `ActorSystem`. That's because the typical use case is to start the system in your main method and then all computation happens on threads that the ActorSystem manages (i.e. the `main()` thread is left to complete and go away - if the threads would be daemonic the app would shut down, which is not what we usually want).

You can do so via:

```
import system.dispatcher
s.runForeach(println).onComplete { _ =>  system.terminate() }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to make Akka use daemon threads? I just don't want it to block the exit of an otherwise complicated application.

Answer (score 0):

Answered at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/u3MXlfVpm40/LHyYruS0HgAJ by https://stackoverflow.com/users/111024/konrad-ktoso-malawski, copied here for convenience; credit to him:

Because Akka uses non-daemonic threads, so it'll keep the app running until you shut-down the ActorSystem.

You can do so via:

```
import system.dispatcher
s.runForeach(println).onComplete { _ =>  system.terminate() }
```